# Surface cover for vertices in three.js

Tags: three.js, visualization, data-visualization

I'm creating a surface visualization for 3D data points. I can draw data points in space with spheres. Now I want to create a surface cover. Here's the jsfiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/dnprock/b9xyfno5/10/

I tried triangulate but it's not generating the surface I want:

triangles = THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape ( vertices, holes );

```
for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));
}
```

What's the way to generate a surface to cover the points?

Answer (score 0):

The face3 takes **the index of three vertices that are already in geometry.vertices** and makes a face. Here, it seems you are trying to make face with original vertex coordinates without including them in geometry of your mesh.
assuming that triangles[i] is an array of three Vector3 objects:

```
for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){
    var first_vertex_index= geometry.vertices.push(triangles[i][0])
    var second_vertex_index= geometry.vertices.push(triangles[i][1])
    var third_vertex_index= geometry.vertices.push(triangles[i][2]) 
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( first_vertex_index, second_vertex_index, third_vertex_index ));
}
```

as you know, the push method returns the index of pushed object in the array, we put the indexes in Face3 not the coordinates.

Comment: triangulate does return indices array. Here's the code with triangulation. https://jsfiddle.net/dnprock/b9xyfno5/10/